# Algorithm or a data structure for this

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There's a problem that says:
Given a number n and n cards that on each card a number is written
we have dice, k times we throw a dice and if the number that dice shows is m, then we have to scratch one of the numbers of cards that is divisble by m
The difficulty is that scratching numbers should be done in O(1)

I couldn't find the solution, maybe an algorithm or a special data structure is needed

I would become happy if any one can help me :)

tnx! :)

Comment: Do you have any bounds on `m`, `k` and `n`? Have you had some ideas you can share?

Answer (score 1):

If you know all numbers on the cards are unique, you could just create an array and store the card object in the array on the index of the number written on them. scratching a number would then just be

```
cardArray[number].scratch()
```

If the numbers are large you would have to create a large array, so it'll be better to create a hash for that.

```
cards = {cardNumber:cardObject, ...}
cards[cardNumber].scratch
```

to scratch all numbers dividable by m create the hash as follows

```
dicemax = 6
scratched = {number: false; ....}
card.scratched? => return scratched[card.number % dicemax]
```

you keep track of which numbers are rolled using the scratched hash. so scratching them of will be in O(1), just rewrite the value of the hash.
checking if a card has been scratched of, you get the number on the card. And see what it's number is modulo the dice max value. if this number has been scratched in the hash the cards is scratched.